# nginx reverse proxy + apache won't display images

Tags: apache, nginx, server

Images served on my sites seem to just redirect to the directoryindex of every site I host or just do not display at all.  Some give a 301 redirect when using wget on the images, others don't.  I use vhosts, but it doesn't seem to be a vhost issue.  Tried reinstalling apache and PHP.

apache version: 2.4.6 
php version: 7.1.29
OS: CentOS Linux 7 (Core)

revelant nginx reverse-proxy conf

```
server {
        listen   80;
        root /var/www/html;
        index index.php index.html index.htm;
        server_name _;
        location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;
        }
        location ~ \.php$ {
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;
         }
         location ~ /\.ht {
                deny all;
        }
    }
~
```

apache httpd.conf relevant part

```
DocumentRoot "/var/www/html"
```

apache vhost .conf file loaded from conf.d

```
<VirtualHost *:8080>
  DocumentRoot /var/www/html
  ServerName domainname.com
  DirectoryIndex index.php
ErrorLog /var/log/httpd/domainname.log
</VirtualHost>
```

The images are .png and .jpg images.  None of them load across all sites using apache. However images with nginx behind the nginx revere-proxy display, so it's probably an apache problem.

Nothing displays in the log files (not even an access notice) while trying to access the images.  Tried tail -f on all the nginx and apache files.  The permissions to the images are set to apache:apache, which is what my OS uses (not www-data).  Permission for images set to 644.

Why won't my images display? :(

Comment: Are you using any rewrites? You should be able to trace the request to debug.

Comment: I'm not using any rewrites.  What do I use to trace the request?